# Show $\cap_m (aB_m)=a(\cap_m B_m)$

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $A\subseteq B$ be domains and let $K$ be the quotient field of $A$ and $a\in A$ be nonzero. I want to prove that $B=aB$ iff $B_m=aB_m$, $\forall\; m$ maximal of $A$.

$\implies$) is clear.

Here is my proof for the other side:

$$B=\bigcap_{m\in \text{MaxSpec(A)}} B_m=\bigcap_{m\in \text{MaxSpec(A)}} aB_m=a\bigcap_{m\in \text{MaxSpec(A)}} B_m=aB.$$

> Questions:
>
> 1.- Is the proof correct?
> 2.- I can not see if the 3ed equality is true. Can you help me about this?

Comment: In the same way one proves $\bigcap_{m\in \text{MaxSpec(A)}}B_m=B$ you can show that $\bigcap_{m\in \text{MaxSpec(A)}} IB_m=I$ for any ideal $I$ of $B$. In particular, this holds for $I=aB$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $a$ is a unit in $B$. If not, then $a\in m$
for some maximal ideal of $B$, and then $aB_m\ne B_m$.

Comment: in the equality $B_m=aB_m$, $m$ is maximal of $A$ not $B$.